# Displaying at a later stage, the form data passed in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a form and I passed the data on an intent called `DisplayPage.java`.
Here's my code snippet.

```
Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayPage.class);
EditText firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextFirstName);
EditText lastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextLastName);

String fname = firstName.getText().toString();
String lname = lastName.getText().toString();

d.putExtra("fname" , fname );
d.putExtra("lname", lname);
```

However, after this, I'm calling another intent called `MainActivity2`.

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

The `MainActivity2` in turn calls on the `DisplayPage` intent as follows-

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity2.this, DisplayPage.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And the `DisplayPage` then receives the data as follows-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return;
}
String fname = extras.getString("fname");
String lname = extras.getString("lname");

final TextView first_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_first);
first_name.setText(String.valueOf(fname));

final TextView first_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_last);
first_name.setText(String.valueOf(lname));
```

Now, if I call the `DisplayPage` directly after passing the data from `MainActivity`, it shows the data passed in the aforementioned `TextView`s. What I want to do is-

1) Pass the form data as given in `MainActivity` to `DisplayPage`.

2)Start an intent called `MainActivity2` (instead of `DisplayPage`) after `MainActivity`

3) Start the intent `DisplayPage` from `MainActivity2` such that the data passed in it from `MainActivity` is displayed.

Comment: just pass data to MA2 from MA and then from MA2 to DisplayPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through the tedious process defined above, we could simply store the values of the data from `MainActivity` into a class where `public static String` values store the input from the user. On the `DisplayPage`, we could easily call the values from the class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, without starting an `Activity` you can't pass data to that `Activity`.

So, what you can do to achieve your goal is

1. Pass those data to `MainActivity2` from `MainActivity`
2. Then pass those to `DisplayPage` from `MainActivity2`

As example, in `MainActivity`,

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
i.putExtra("fname" , fname );
i.putExtra("lname", lname);
startActivity(i);
```

and then in `MainActivity2`,

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, DisplayPage.class);
d.putExtra("fname" , getIntent().getStringExtra("fname"));
d.putExtra("lname", getIntent().getStringExtra("lname"));
startActivity(d);
```

Comment: I see. So, is there any workaround to do what I want to do?
There're some fields of the form on MainActivity like, First Name, Last Name, Age, etc. 
Then MainActivity2 has some more fields like Address, City, etc. ANd then finally the third page i.e. DisplayPage displays the data inputted by the user. How do I do that?

Comment: Yes, this would surely work. 
However, wouldn't that require a lot of code for passing it from one activity to another? It's okay for one extra activity, but in case the number of activities increase, it would be really tedious.

Comment: How about this?
We could create a class and pass the value of the data from MainActivity into public static string values and then access it on the final DisplayPage.

Comment: Yeah...you can do that and I think that will be better choice instead of passing data through multiple activities to get those data in the destination class.